# PHP process ram and cpu usage (windows)

Tags: windows, php, cpu, ram, process

I making a webadmin system and I want to monitor the CPU and RAM usage of a process in PHP

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear whether you want to monitor the PHP process, or monitor another process using a script you wrote in PHP.

Answer (score 6):

"Counters and Logs to Monitor" => http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300504

Save as CSV and read it() by PHP

[OR]

http://pecl.php.net/package/win32ps

[OR]

Use WMI:

```
<?PHP
#error_reporting(1);
$wmi = new COM("WinMgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}") ;


$cpus = $wmi->ExecQuery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor");

foreach ($cpus as $cpu) :
      echo $cpu->LoadPercentage . '%';
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it works perfectly. Combine this with AJAX and a JAVASCRIPT timer so you get every xy seconds the usage of your cpu&ram.

```
function get_server_cpu_usage(){

    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    return $load[0];

}


function get_server_memory_usage(){

    $free = shell_exec('free');
    $free = (string)trim($free);
    $free_arr = explode("\n", $free);
    $mem = explode(" ", $free_arr[1]);
    $mem = array_filter($mem);
    $mem = array_merge($mem);
    $memory_usage = $mem[2]/$mem[1]*100;

    return $memory_usage;
}

echo '<h4>Server Memory usage: ' . number_format(get_server_memory_usage(), 2) . '%</h4><span style="width:' . get_server_memory_usage() . '%"></span<br>
<h4>Server CPU usage: '     . get_server_cpu_usage() . '% </h4><span style="width:' . get_server_cpu_usage() . '%"></span>';
```